# How to normalize the brightness of a video

Tags: video, normalization, video-processing

I want to normalize the brightness of the video, so as not to have its differences. I tried to use the histogram equalization for each frame and then merge these frames into new videos, but this action did not work. The brightness difference between frames became even greater. Is there a way to make the brightness differences between each frame be minimal?

Comment: I am kind of an expert in what you try to do but i did not at all get your question. Please edit it and add a lot more information. Including what you all technoligies and methods you already tried and why they did not work for you

Comment: @Harry First of all I want  to do it via Python.  I tried to use the histogram equalization for each frame and then merge these frames into new videos, but this action did not work. I want  to normalize the brigtness of a all frames on video.

Comment: Could you please post your code so far? As I understand, if you want to normalise brightness between frames, you have to remember brightnesses of neighbouring frames and then try to change current one's brightness to average. If you work with separated frames, any editing/processing on a frame alone makes randomness in brightness even bigger.